# Error upon trying to use SolanaCLI on a local enviorment by following steps from the docs

Tags: solana-cli

Upon, trying to follow the steps as stated on [this link](https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/local), I receive the following errors, I followed all the steps correctly and tried all the available work arounds for the same, none of them seem to work for me.
[image: The error]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the shell doesn’t have Solana in its path. Here is same [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69983608/how-to-install-solana-on-windows) to install Solana on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

try to restart your shell (if you haven't exported new path)